# Filtering google maps markers with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to filter my google maps markers from a checkbox, based on [this V3 example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html). My checkbox html is:

```
<form action="#">
  Attractions: <input type="checkbox" id="attractionbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'attraction')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  Food and Drink: <input type="checkbox" id="foodbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'food')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  Hotels: <input type="checkbox" id="hotelbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'hotel')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  Towns/Cities: <input type="checkbox" id="citybox" onclick="boxclick(this,'city')" /><br />
</form>
```

My javascript is below. I can't seem to get the filters to work - at present all the markers appear on the map regardless of the state of the checkboxes. I'm guessing I've just got some of my variables in the wrong place, but I haven't been able to crack the problem so far! Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var map;
var infowindow;
var image = [];
var gmarkers = [];

  image['attraction'] = 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/beach.png'; 
  image['food'] = 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/restaurant.png';
  image['hotel'] = 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/hotel.png';
  image['city'] = 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/smallcity.png';

function mapInit(){
    var centerCoord = new google.maps.LatLng(18.23, -66.39); 
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: centerCoord,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.close();
    });

    jQuery.getJSON("/places", function(json) {
      if (json.length > 0) {
        for (i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
          var place = json[i];
          var category = json[i].tag;
          addLocation(place,category);
        }
      }
    });

    function addLocation(place,category) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(place.lat, place.lng),
        map: map,
        title: place.name,
        icon: image[place.tag]
      });

      marker.mycategory = category;
      gmarkers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "<h3>"+ place.name +"</h3><p>" + place.tag +"</p><a href='/places/"+place.id+"'>Show more!</a>"
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function show(category) {
      for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
        if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
          gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
        }
      }
      document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
    }

    function hide(category) {
      for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
        if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
          gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
        }
      }
      document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
      infowindow.close();
    }

    function boxclick(box,category) {
      if (box.checked) {
        show(category);
      } else {
        hide(category);
      }
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    mapInit();
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that the `boxclick()` function is enclosed within the scope of the `mapInit()` function, and therefore `boxclick()` is not accessible from outside `mapInit()`. You should remove the `onclick` events from your HTML input fields, and then define the event handlers within the `mapInit()` function as follows:

```
function mapInit() {

  // ...

  $('#attractionbox').click(function () {
    boxclick(this, 'attraction');
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks - removing the inline js was going to be my next challenge, so that's solved both problems! I'm a bit confused about the global variables however - I thought by declaring these before mapInit() (as I have done for map, infoWindow, image and gmarkers) they would no longer be implied?

Comment: @Sonia: Sorry, I really didn't notice they were declared up there :) Removed that part from my answer.