# GM markers on/off based on categories & checkboxes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, checkbox, filter, google-maps-markers

I am trying to have markers in different categories & then present them on map by using checkboxes. I have followed an approach found on stackoverflow by [@Sonia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324573/filtering-google-maps-markers-with-a-checkbox) 2 yrs ago.

my sample js is like this:

```
var map;
var marker;
var image = [];
image['must']='icons/star.png';
var markerMust = [];

function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.0086, 24.928),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };        

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(34.957825, 25.041315), 
map: map,
title: 'placename',
clickable: true,
    category: 'must',
icon: 'icons/star.png'  
});

markerMust.push(marker);

$('#mustB').click(function () {
boxclick(this, 'must');
}); 
        }    //map initialization ends here
var i;

function toggleMarkers(markerMust) {
for (i=0; i<markerMust.length i++) {
if (markerMust[i].category == category) {

markerMust[i].setVisible(true);
}
}
document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
}
function boxclick(box, category){
if (box.checked){
toggleMarkers(markerMust);
}
}
```

*issues identified:

- map does not start
- is the marker declaration correct for category; and is marker category called correctly afterwards?
- not sure if function toggleMarkers() syntax is correct, given that no further additions to the code exist
- this is a sample of 100+ markers map, with only one category shown, same approach is followed for the rest of the categories

HTML:

```
<html>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:1200px; height:800px;"></div>
<form action="#">
Must Visit: <input type ="checkbox" id="mustB" onclick="boxclick(this,'must')">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the map is working again, but without the inclusion of different categories (category arrays) nor push.markers at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took away the jQuery statement, and it worked perfectly without it :D

```
$('#mustB').click(function () {
boxclick(this, 'must');
});
```